# How to subset a dataset by time but not date?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a list of times and dates. I want to subset it so I only have entries between 06:30:00 and 07:30:00. I have tried subsetting it using the following function:
`field1_temp$Time<-field1_temp$Time["T06:30:00/T07:30:00"]`.

The structure of the dataset is as follows:

```
> str(field1_temp)
'data.frame':   17066 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ No.         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Time        : POSIXlt, format: "2021-02-08 14:56:07" "2021-02-08 14:57:07" "2021-02-08 14:58:07" ...
 $ Temperature.: num  6.8 6.5 6 5 4.7 4.8 4.2 3.6 2.9 2.3 ...
```

When running the function I only returned NAs, despite their being times in the right period specified.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag regarding how to ask a question and, in particular, show the input in a reproducible form. I have done it for  you this time in the Note at the end of the my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you `Time` in `POSIXlt` format `hour` and `min` information should be present in itself. Try :

```
result <- field1_temp[with(field1_temp$Time, hour == 6 & min >= 30 | 
                                             hour == 7 & min <= 30), ]
```

Comment: Judging from his own attempts I think it would be useful for him to know why and how your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, we read it into a zoo object, convert that to xts and  finally we subset it using the notation in the question. The code below also converts the POSIXlt date times to POSIXct which is a more suitable class for time series.  You can turn it back to data frame using `fortify.zoo(x0)` but it's probably better to just leave it as an xts object to facilitate access to the time series functionality it and zoo provide.

```
library(xts)

z <- read.zoo(d, index = "Time", FUN = as.POSIXct)
x <- as.xts(z)
x0 <- x["T14:56:00/T14:56:59"]
x0
                    No Temperature
2021-02-08 14:56:07  1         6.8
```

### Note

```
d <- data.frame(No = 1:2,
 Time =  as.POSIXlt(c("2021-02-08 14:56:07", "2021-02-08 14:57:07")),
 Temperature = c(6.8, 6.5))
```